# Where can I find a time scale (or anything similar) listing the main discoveries and achievments in mathematics?

Tags: math-history

I am currently preparing my next physics exam, and I got courious if there may be on the Net some sort of time scale of mathematical discoveries, so that I could compare discoveries and achievements in physics with the mathematic instruments available at the time.
While there is large abundance of such graphs for computer science and physics, maths related ones are quite hard to find..
Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_mathematics

Comment: I'd like to add: there's a book by Clifford A. Pickover that enlist some mathematical gems through the ages.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira: ok, I will have a look at it whenever I get the chance.. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia has such a list at [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_mathematics).